# Lost Safari on my iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

My Safari is no longer showing on my iPhone 5. Where can I find it?

Comment: Search it on the Spotlight - is it showing up or not? please let us know - reboot and check again - if it is still not showing up i have another Idea

Comment: @bMalum make that in a answer

Answer (score 6):

Search for it with **Spotlight** — does it show up or not?

Reboot and check again. If it is still not showing up you can check if Safari is allowed in Settings → General → Restrictions → Safari.

In Spotlight, on the right of the icon and app name the Folder Name is displayed so you can find the location of the Safari icon.

Answer (score 0):

Safari, as one of the built in apps of iOS, can't be uninstalled. Therefore, check Spotlight to see if you've misplaced it in a folder. Also check Restrictions as Safari can be disabled there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're phone is jailbroken and you have the "Dockshift" tweak remove it and your missing icons will most likely appear at the bottom of your homescreen where the dock was hidden with that tweak.